# XCode 14, AdMob and Info.plist

Tags: ios, admob

Google Admob requires adding keys to Info.plist, yet in the latest versions of XCode the Info.plist file is auto generated.

Adding an Info.plist file manually with the required Admob keys creates a conflict between the two files and results in a build error.

[image]

Going into project settings and disabling the auto generation of the Info.plist file results in an error about code signing due to missing Info.plist file, the file is located in the project main directory (where the source files are located), one below the project root.

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution found - *Do not create the Info.plist manually*

Go to Project targets->Info->Custom iOS Target Properties - And add a custom key with any value.

The Info.plit file will be added to your project.